# Environment- (or application-) specific functions

Tags: php, laravel

Creating a web app in Laravel that will be cloned into multiple separate instances. I realise that it's possible to put in place application-specific variables in the .env file so, for example, if the application had a commission rate that was applicable to certain calculations carried out within it, one could specify one conversion rate in the .env file for one installation, and a different one in a different installation.

My question, though, is how best to do that with environment-specific functions? So if each installation had a different way of working out how the commission was calculated, what would be the best way of building the app such that it works for all, but then one drops in the installation-specific method of calculating commission for that application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to still use environment specific variables, but write your function implementations around those variables. In your example, you could have different commission rates, and several methods of calculating commission. You could have a variable which defines which method to use like this:

```
class CommissionCalculator
{
    public function calculate()
    {
        $method = config('commission.method');
        $rate = config('commission.rate');
        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
            return $this->$method($rate);
        }

        // throw an exception
    }

    public function method1($rate)
    {
        // Implement method1
    }
}
```

**config/commission.php**

```
return [
    'rate' => env('COMMISSION_RATE'),
    'method' => env('COMMISSION_METHOD')
];
```

**.env**

```
COMMISSION_RATE=1
COMMISSION_METHOD=method1
```

Comment: Thank you. I think all the answers tend to the fact that it's not possible to have a pure method in the environment configuration, but this was the best answer (particularly the combination of storing the method name and using method_exists, which I'd not considered).

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `CALCULATION_METHOD` variable in your `.env.` file. You can read that value in your calculate method and let the logic depend on that.

Every piece of "installation-specific" configuration should be stored in the `.env` file.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a base value in env file and load the base value in config file and add code to override this config parameter in appserviceprovider.php boot method.

The logic is that when app boot it check condition from db and if fulfilled it override the config value that means your calculation changed automatically